# Dropdown List ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There are 2 drop down list:

1. Project
2. Plot Details

**My Question is:** Once `Project` is selected then `Plot Details` Get Populated properly but, when `Plot Details` of Dropdown is get select then Chrome hangs up.

To continue, I have to refresh the page. I want the `Plot Details`(drop down) value to call another ajax call.

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get_member_name').live('change', function() {
        alert('hello')
        var project = $('#project').val();
        var plot_details = $('#plot_details').val();
        var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
        if (project && plot_details) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "admin/get_member_name",
                data: {'category': category},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result)
                }
            })
        }
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">
           Plot Details :
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
           <select class="form-control get_member_name" name="plot_details" required="required" id="plot_details">
                <option value="" id="opp12">Select Plot</option>
           </select>
      </div>
 </div>
```

**PHP**

```
public function get_plot_details() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('role_id') == 1) {
        $data['record'] = $this->db->get_where('plot_details', array('project_id' => $this->input->post('project')))->result();
        print_r($this->load->view('admin/ajax_data', $data, TRUE));
    } else {
        redirect('home/login');
    }
}
```

**View Page**

```
if (isset($record) && $record != NULL && $record != "") {
    foreach ($record as $m) {
        echo '<option value="' . $m->id . '">&nbsp;' . $m->plot_number . '  Area ' . $m->total_area . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can help you without the code.

Comment: k Wait I'll post the Code...

Comment: when i will Select the Plot Details Drop down list then i have set alert in the js code but it didn't response any thing and Sudden It Hang.

Comment: Do you get console errors?

Comment: Where do you set `var category` from your `data` in your ajax?

Comment: Did you try using separate class names for each drop downs. Means one function for populating Plot Details while Project changes and another function triggered when Plot changes. eg: $(".project").on("change", function(){ .......ajax...........}); $(".plot").on("change", function(){ .......ajax...........});

Comment: Also, on the jQuery site, they say: **As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().**

Comment: You are sending data: {'category': category}, where category is not present. And in your php trying to fetch the record using project ..$this->input->post('project'). From where 'project' came from? Might be this is the issue.

Comment: So instead of data: {'category': category} use data: {'project': project}

Answer (score 0):

I could see you have used 'project' in your php to fetch the records from DB. But in your ajax you are passing the request data 'category'. Might be this one is causing issue. So instead of

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: base_url + "admin/get_member_name",
     data: {'category': category},
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(result) {
                 alert(result)
              }
 })
```

use

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: base_url + "admin/get_member_name",
         data: {'project': project},
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(result) {
                     alert(result)
                  }
     })
```

Comment: Ohhhoo .... Thanx a lot that was the silly mistake...

Thank u all user to helping me.